# Basic VBS help - optimizing VBS script

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I found this simple script that outputs the logical disk sizes.

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk")

For Each objDisk in colDisks
    Wscript.Echo "DeviceID: " & objDisk.DeviceID & " with a Disk Size: " & objDisk.Size

Next
```

My VBS skills are very poor and I need help:

1. I would like to get a single size number of ONLY the C and D partitions added together
2. if the size (from step1) is not equal to 500-GB (between 450,000,000,000 and 550,000,000,000) I need the computer to prompt a warning and "press any key" to continue
3. I don't want a pop-up window since this is going to run from the prompt of WinPE, is it possible to get the output in the prompt window?

I'm asking a lot so thank you in advance if you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to start your script using cscript.
The code for this comes from http://ask.metafilter.com/79481/vbscript-printing-to-command-line
This allows the echos to go to the command line instead of a Message box.

```
CheckStartMode
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk")

For Each objDisk in colDisks
    If(objDisk.DeviceID="C:" or objDisk.DeviceID="D:") then
        Wscript.Echo "DeviceID: " & objDisk.DeviceID & " with a Disk Size: " & objDisk.Size
        TotalSize = CCur(TotalSize) + CCur(objDisk.Size)
    End if
Next
If(TotalSize <450000000000 or TotalSize >550000000000) then
    Wscript.Echo "Disk size of " & TotalSize & " is out of range."
    Wscript.Echo "Press enter to contine."
    z = WScript.StdIn.Read(1)
End if

Wscript.Echo "Complete, Press enter to end."
z = WScript.StdIn.Read(1)
Sub CheckStartMode
     ' Returns the running executable as upper case from the last \ symbol
     strStartExe    = UCase( Mid( wscript.fullname, instrRev(wscript.fullname, "\") + 1 ) )

     If Not strStartExe = "CSCRIPT.EXE" Then
          ' This wasn't launched with cscript.exe, so relaunch using cscript.exe explicitly!
          ' wscript.scriptfullname is the full path to the actual script

          set           oSh = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
          oSh.Run   "cscript.exe """ & wscript.scriptfullname & """"
          wscript.quit

     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the reply!! The total size should be C + D (added together) and then checked against (objDisk.Size<450000000000 or objDisk.Size>550000000000), right now they seem to be individual. I'm sorry I wasn't specific enough in my initial post :(

Comment: Props for the CheckStartMode. Neat! @ToastMan, make something like `If objDisk.DeviceID="C:" Then SizeC = objDisk.Size` and `If objDisk.DeviceID="D:" Then SizeD = objDisk.Size`. After the for-each-next loop, you add both sizes: `If (SizeC + SizeD) <450000000000 or (SizeC + SizeD) >550000000000 then Wscript.Echo "Disk size is out of range."`

Comment: AutomatedChaos is correct. I have edited the answer to reflect this change.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for the reply!! your time is appreciated. The "TotalSize = TotalSize + objDisk.Size" seems to put both numbers size by size, it doesn't performs an "addition" action on the 2 numbers. Test it, you'll see. So the TotalSize value end up being really HUGE. Example: If C is 12500 and D is 6500, TotalSize will equal to 125006500 and not 12500 + 6500 = 19000.

Comment: I found the solution:  TotalSize = CCur(TotalSize) + CCur(objDisk.Size)